# WebView2 throws timeout Exception while initialization for some users

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, webview2

My webview2 initialization doesn't work for some group of users, But for some it works properly. It throws an timeout exception for some users.
Below is my code-

```
public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        EnsureTemplate();
        Browser.NavigationStarting += Browser_NavigationStarting;
        Browser.NavigationCompleted += Browser_NavigationCompleted;
        Browser.PreviewKeyDown += Browser_PreviewKeyDown;
        Browser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += Browser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        var cachePath = WebUIConfigSection.Current.AbsoluteCachePath;
        var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, cachePath, null);
        await Browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);
    }
```

Exception details-

Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Target site: Void ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)

Message: This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (HRESULT: 0x800705B4)

Source: mscorlib

Stacktrace:

`vid System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) vid Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.d__54.MoveNext() vid System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() vid System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) vid Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<g__Init|0>d.MoveNext()`

Comment: It seems to come from `CoreWebView2Environment`. I would try to log the `cachePath`, if it's correct.

Comment: Cache path is correct it is pointing to %appdata%roaming and its subfolder as we mentions in our config

Comment: For further investigating the issue I created release folder on my system with 64 bit. And asked user to run the application through this release folder. And they are able to run it successfully. That means there is some problem with the installed version only.
We use Clickonce to create and deploy the application. I am not sure what could be the issue with the clickonce deployed version.

Comment: In our future investigation, We found that the issue is with the shortcut(created by ClickOnce) only. The webview doesn't work if opened with shortcut. If we open it from the acture folder path, where it is installed on user's machine, It works fine.

Does anyone has any idea what is wrong with the shortcut?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with the information described in details.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to avoid the exception is to set a timer that does a .Stop() when the query exceeded a certain time (configurable).

You could use the same to determine how long it takes WebView to timeout.

I assume that the target page is not using frames.

Comment: For further investigating the issue I created release folder on my system with 64 bit. And asked user to run the application through this release folder. And they are able to run it successfully. That means there is some problem with the installed version only.
We use Clickonce to create and deploy the application. I am not sure what could be the issue with the clickonce deployed version.

Comment: The issue went away once I saturated the application with event handlers for every possible event (including frames) and added a timeout feature.

Thanks!

Comment: In our future investigation, We found that the issue is with the shortcut(created by ClickOnce) only. The webview doesn't work if opened with shortcut. If we open it from the acture folder path, where it is installed on user's machine, It works fine.